# React Typescript with hooks : Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have this error :  Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I don't know why is an error, can anyone help?

App.tsx file :

```js
const [showPerPage] =useState(1);
const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({ start: 0, end: showPerPage, });


const onPaginationChange = (start, end) => { 
setPagination({ start, end });
};

<Grid container lg={12} xs={12} sm={12}> {list.slice(pagination.start, pagination.end).map((post) => (
 <h5>{post.id}</h5> ))
} 

<UsePagination 
showPerPage={showPerPage}
onPaginationChange={onPaginationChange} 
total={list.length} /> 
</Grid>
```

ReactJS component code: UsePagination.tsx file

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const UsePagination = ({ showPerPage, onPaginationChange, total }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const [numberOfButtons] = useState(Math.ceil(total / showPerPage));

  useEffect(() => {
    const value = showPerPage * counter;
    onPaginationChange(value - showPerPage, value);
  }, [counter]);

  const onButtonClick = (type) => {
    if (type === 'prev') {
      if (counter === 1) {
        setCounter(1);
      } else {
        setCounter(counter - 1);
      }
    } else if (type === 'next') {
      if (numberOfButtons === counter) {
        setCounter(counter);
      } else {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <nav className="hd-pagination">
        <ul className={'hd-pagination__wrapper'}>
          <li className="hd-pagination__item hd-pagination__button">
            <button
              type="button"
              data-testid="pagination-prev-button"
              onClick={() => onButtonClick('prev')}
              className="hd-pagination__link"
            >
              pre
            </button>
          </li>
          {new Array(numberOfButtons).fill('').map((el, index) => (
            <li
              key={el}
              className={`hd-pagination__item ${index + 1 === counter ? 'active' : null}`}
            >
              <button
                type="button"
                data-testid="pagination-button-number"
                data-automation-id="instantCheckout-pagination-button"
                onClick={() => setCounter(index + 1)}
                className={`hd-pagination__link`}
              >
                {index + 1}
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
          <li className={'hd-pagination__item hd-pagination__button'}>
            <button
              type="button"
              data-testid="pagination-next-button"
              onClick={() => onButtonClick('next')}
              className={'hd-pagination__link'}
            >
              Next
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: key={el} looks wrong if el is always the empty string, maybe use some unique id + the index as key?

Comment: What happens when you call `onPaginationChange`? Can we see the parent component?

Comment: const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({
    start: 0,
    end: showPerPage,
  });               const onPaginationChange = (start, end) => {
    setPagination({ start, end });
  };              <Grid container lg={12} xs={12} sm={12}>      
          {list.slice(pagination.start, pagination.end).map((post) => (     
              <h5>#{post.id}</h5>     
          ))}
             <UsePagination
          showPerPage={showPerPage}
          onPaginationChange={onPaginationChange}
          total={list.length}
        />
      </Grid>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code rather than comment, @samir.

Comment: i updated code ,i noticed that problem with useEffect only .is it possible without useEffect .Actually i am new in react .Thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will get that error whenever you have an infinite loop on your componentDidMound or useEffect (in your case `App.tsx` file)

for solving your problem it's better to remove `onPaginationChange` function in useEffect of `UsePagination.tsx` file and add that function to `onClick` event of your buttons.

try like this:

```
<button
  type="button"
  data-testid="pagination-button-number"
  data-automation-id="instantCheckout-pagination-button"
  onClick={() => {
              const value = showPerPage * (index + 1)
              setCounter(index + 1)
              onPaginationChange(value - showPerPage, value)
          }}
  className={`hd-pagination__link`}
>
  {index + 1}
</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much for helped ,Its working now but prev button and right button is not working

Comment: you should call `onPaginationChange` but you need to get current state of page and you understood this logic very well and created current state of your page so you just need to change only `value` variable like this :  `const value = showPerPage *  counter`